# JQuery/Javascript to keep Absolutely Positioned div in place with browser zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser, resize

Looking at [this layout,](http://www.freestyle.mvla.net/WebAudio/APDivs.html) I want to use jQuery/Javascript to put the Red Box, in the Gray Container under the left small Blue Box whether zooming in or out with any browser.

I am trying to accomplish this by NOT putting the redbox #badplacement div inside the Gray Container's #outerwrapper div. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

(To start, I change the #badplacement css left to 243px, on normal browser zoom level, where it is under the small blue box.)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q56up/

Comment: if you set it up on http://jsfiddle.net/ you might get quicker responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the outerwrapper div with css rules but without background and place it over the original (position:absolute, z-index:1). Put Red Box inside and position it relative.

Comment: is there a simpler way without cloning?

Comment: I would go with pasting Red Box with javascript inside outerwrapper. In html source Red Box would be outside, and later in DOM would be inside. Is it possible way?